# Glob matching not working in Storybook config?

Tags: glob, storybook

I have this in my main.js:

`stories: ['../src/components/**/*'],`

But it simply won't load. The UI says "no stories found" in so many words.

If I change it to this, it works:

`stories: ['../src/components/MySpecificComponent/.stories/*'],`

But of course it only loads the stories for that specific component. I cannot imagine what the issue is here.

Comment: did you get any headstart as I am also facing the same bug

Comment: Yes! It was the name of the folder that I was putting the stories in. It's because there's a peculiarity around how glob matching works with files and folders that start with a dot. See "dots" in the docs here, hope this helps https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Comment: Basically either the glob pattern has to specifically account for the dot, or else just change the folder name to not have a dot.

Comment: got it now it is solved thanks ;-D @temporary_user_name